# How to call this promise chain right

Tags: javascript, promise

I use the following code with blueBird lib but in the console I got error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

And I dont see the console.log in the **then** ([SUCESS]) why?

I've two files 
1.index.html with the following code

```
<html>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.1.1/bluebird.js'></script>
```

2. and script.js with the following code

```js
var stepOne = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Step 1 -->Successfully Resolving");
        resolve();
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Step 1 -->First timeout, rejecting the promise");
        reject();
    }, 2000);
}).catch(function () {
        console.log("Step 1 -->Timed out 1 ... retrying");
    });


var stepTwo = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Step 2 -->Successfully Resolving Step two");
        resolve();
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Step 2 -->First timeout, rejecting the promise");
        reject();
    }, 2000);
}).catch(function () {
        console.log("Step 2 -->timed out 2 ... retrying");
    });


stepOne.then(function () {
    console.log("[SUCCESS] Step 1");
}).stepTwo.then(function () {
        console.log("[Success] Step 2");
    })
```

Comment: As it is, the structure of your code is `PROMISE . then() . PROMISE . then()`. So you are trying to access the `stepTwo` property of the promise returned by `then`, which doesn't exist. What are you trying to do, in words?

Comment: Hey, please consider changing the accepted mark on this question. Aside from my answer, both other answers are wrong, because they would not cause one action to run after the other.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you need `stepOne` to happen before `stepTwo` does, you should do as follows:

```
var stepOne = function() {
    var stepOnePromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 1 -->Successfully Resolving");
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 1 -->First timeout, rejecting the promise");
            reject();
        }, 2000);
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("Step 1 -->Timed out 1 ... retrying");
    });
    return stepOnePromise;
}

var stepTwo = function() {
    var stepTwoPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 2 -->Successfully Resolving Step two");
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Step 2 -->First timeout, rejecting the promise");
            reject();
        }, 2000);
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("Step 2 -->timed out 2 ... retrying");
    });
    return stepTwoPromise;
}

stepOne().then(function () {
    console.log("[SUCCESS] Step 1");
})
.then(stepTwo)
.then(function () {
    console.log("[Success] Step 2");
});
```

I have to add, though, that right now the `console.log` (that says 'success') as well as `stepTwo` will be called when rejecting the first promise (after the inner `catch` handles it) and then resolving it has no meaning. I guess this is only an abstraction of the code, and your retrial mechanism is different, so it might work as wanted anyway...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - is there a way to dis-accept / delete it with no action required from @shopia?

Comment: You can fix your answer, at that point you can ping me which would cause cause me to reverse my downvote and it'd draw more attention to this question/answer and remove the negative rep. If you'd like it deleted you can also mod flag it - but I warmly recommend fixing it instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have a bit of a misunderstanding about what a Promise is. A Promise is a proxy for a **value**, not for an **action**. Code passed to the Promise constructor is executed **immediately**, so your code will always run all at once, and not one after another. (You can't "run" a Promise just like you can't "run" a Number or a Boolean. You can, however, run a function)

What you want to do is have `step1` and `step2` **functions** which *return a Promise*.

```
const step1 = () => new Promise(...); // Step 1 code in this promise
const step2 = () => new Promise(...); // Step 2 code in this promise

// By this point, nothing runs, we only defined functions.

step1() // Run step one
  .then(() => console.log('[SUCCESS] Step 1');
  .then(step2); // Run step two
  .then(() => console.log('[SUCCESS] Step 2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain like this

```
stepOne.then(function () {

}).stepTwo.then(function () {
```

as you're trying to access the `stepTwo` property of the returned result from `then`, which doesn't have a `stepTwo` property.

You have to do it like this, keeping the variables *(and promises)* separate

```
stepOne.then(function () {
    console.log("[SUCCESS] Step 1");
});

stepTwo.then(function () {
        console.log("[Success] Step 2");
});
```

or if you want to wait for all promises to finish, you can use `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all([stepOne, stepTwo]).then(function() {
    console.log("both");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but if I want to keep it under chain i.e. when stepOne is finished then just start step two, how would you do it?

Comment: If you just want to execute them in series, you can use `Promise.mapSeries([stepOne, stepTwo])`